# 2 variables in a function getting the same date value

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

having a small issue with my dates. I have a function which receives a date and is stored into a few variables. I set the passed in date to different dates on both variables, but when run, it's the same. Following is a snippet

```
function dateChange(dateInput){
var prevWeek = dateInput; 
var prevMonth = dateInput;
prevWeek.setDate(prevWeek.getDate()-7);
prevMonth.setDate(prevMonth.getDate()-30); 

 var $prev_month_link = $( '<a>' )
      .html( "month" )
      .click(function(event){
          //prevMonth = new Date();
          alert("click prevMonth: "+prevMonth);
        //dateChange( prevMonth ) 
        prevMonth = prevMonth.substring(3,5)+"/"+prevMonth.substring(0,2)+"/"+prevMonth.substring(6,10)
        var prevMonth2 = new Date(prevMonth);
        //alert("line 132, current2 is: "+prevMonth2);
        dateChange(prevMonth2);
        event.stopPropagation();
      })
      .addClass("prevMonth")
      .attr('data-name', prevMonth)
      .appendTo( $prev_container )

      var $prev_week_link = $( '<a>' )
      .html( "week" )
      .click(function(event){
          alert("click prevWeek: "+prevWeek);
        prevWeek = prevWeek.substring(3,5)+"/"+prevWeek.substring(0,2)+"/"+prevWeek.substring(6,10)
        var prevWeek2 = new Date(prevWeek);
        dateChange( prevWeek2 ) 
        event.stopPropagation();
      })
      .addClass("prevWeek")
      .attr('data-name', prevWeek)
      .appendTo( $prev_container )
}
```

My problem is prevWeek and prevMonth have the same date, even though I set them differently. I'm not sure if it's because of the click event taking place.
example you can see here http://www.ccy.com.au/availability/

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might think that these two lines copy `dateInput` into `prevWeek` and `prevMonth`:

```
var prevWeek = dateInput; 
var prevMonth = dateInput;
```

Not so. They make `prevWeek` and `prevMonth` point to the same place. When you then call methods on them:

```
prevWeek.setDate(prevWeek.getDate()-7);
prevMonth.setDate(prevMonth.getDate()-30);
```

You're just changing the object they're pointing to; it's equivalent to

```
dateInput.setDate(dateInput.getDate()-7);
dateInput.setDate(dateInput.getDate()-30);
```

Probably not what you wanted. To actually copy the date, use `new Date`, passing it the date you want to copy:

```
var prevWeek = new Date(dateInput); 
var prevMonth = new Date(dateInput);
```

This makes them each point to a new, non-identical `Date` representing the same moment in time.

Comment: I feel like the biggest knob. I had:
var prevWeek = new Date(dateInput); 
var prevMonth = new Date(dateInput);
commented out and hidden in DreamWeaver.. I've been working on this for far too long, thank you thank you thank you sir!